# Explaining an Algorithm (using Partition from Quicksort)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time

Regarding this algorithm:

```
Algo(A, p, r)
if p ≤ r then
  q ← Partition(A,p,r)
if q == r then
  return A[q]
else
  return Algo(A,q+1,r)
end
end
```

While partition is:

```
Partition(A,p,r)
x=A[r]; j=r; i=p-1;
While true
    repeat j ← j - 1
       until A[j]<x
    repeat i ← i +1
       until A[i] >= x
    if i<j
       then A[i] ←→ A[j] % swap
       else A[j+1] ←→ A[r]
          return j+1
```

I need to explain what Algo do.

So Partition is from Quicksort, dealing with the pivot.

Partition basically returns the index of the pivot, and then in Algo, we are taking the index and assigning it into q.

We are keep doing it until q==r, but I don't understand what Algo really does, my best guess is that it returns the Max value of the array, and what is the running time of something like this.

Any help will be amazing!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67314202/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139642/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20science,%20quickselect%20is,known%20as%20Hoare%27s%20selection%20algorithm.) implementation of  **k-smallest** algorithm (here r-smallest).

Intended to get k-th statistics  - for example, array/list *median* as n/2-th element in sorted order.

For example, you have data `{9, 5, 3, 1, 8}`  with length `n=5`.
Sorted array with the same elements: `{1, 3, 5, 8, 9}`.
Median element is 5, 1st smallest is 1, 2-nd smallest is 3 .. 5th smallest (here largest) is 9.

Of course, it is possible to sort array and get `A[n/2]` or `A[k]`, but full sorting takes some resources (time complexity is `O(nlogn)`)
Quickselect allows to solve this problem quickly, wasting less resources (time complexity is `O(n)` in average)

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Can you explain more please? I do not understand what k-smallest algorithm means, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! I think that this algorithm will return the max element in the array, doesn't it?

Comment: It will return max element only if you call function with `r=A.length-1`

Comment: Cool - thank you! I have one more question, can you explain me how to write the recurrence relation for the worst case running time? I understand that the worst case is O(n^2), which can happen if we get a sorted array and by choosing the pivot to be the first element of the array, but how can I write it as a T(n) formula? Thanks!! :)

Comment: In the worst case we make n-1 steps and separate out only one element, so `T(n) = T(n-1) + n-1`

Comment: Thank you! We know that Partition is Theta(n^2) so is it also: `T(n)=T(n-1)+Theta(n^2)` ?

Comment: No. There is no Theta(n^2) work at every stage, it is for final result. I showed formula. Summing sequence for n steps gives n(n-1)/2 ~ n^2  operations.